# How can I capture substrings from Excel text by font color alone?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using vlookup to capture selected cells from a large spreadsheet in the usual way. However, the text I'm selecting from uses a colored font that conveys information that I need to preserve. But vlookup doesn't' copy the formatting. I see these possibilities:

a) Use vlookup in some way that preserves the formatting -not likely

b) Put brackets or some delimiter around the colored text that will be transferred with the vlookup.

[image: Need to identify where the green text starts and ends]

I don't care about the color as such, I just need to preserve the fact that a given substring is "special".  If need be, I can transfer the text to Word or some other application. Thanks as always.

Comment: If you use `MATCH()/INDEX()` rather than `VLOOKUP()` you will know the location of the cell you get getting...you may be able to use some form of Conditional Formatting to format the result...just an idea...

Comment: Don't see how that helps. I need to identify where the green text starts and ends.  MS Word can select text based on formatting...perhaps this should be a word question, not excel....

Comment: There is no way for that. Worksheet functions doesn't have any information on text formatting

Answer (score 0):

The only feature Excel has that can discriminate between different cells or pieces of text based on their colour is VBA. Excel is not a text editor or really designed for elaborate reports or presentations - it's an analysis tool. Word or Powerpoint can select based on text colour, because they're presentational tools.

Your second possibility, of adding delimiting characters, is the best solution in an Excel environment; using a different application may well be your best bet.

I do rather wish that Excel didn't provide quite so many formatting options, especially in later versions - humans are visually oriented, so we keep on using formatting where what computers really need is clear delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

This function does the job:

```
Function GetColorText(pRange As range) As String
    Dim xOut As String
    Dim xValue As String
    Dim i As Long
    xValue = pRange.Text

    For i = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)

        If pRange.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(112, 173, 71) Then
            xOut = xOut & VBA.Mid(xValue, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    GetColorText = xOut
End Function
```

The parameters of RGB need to be changed to match the color that you are looking for. Also, if there are multiple substrings in a single cell, they will be concatenated together.